# Looking for a way to wait for only all visible elements using Java Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to develop a generic method for my framework that will click a button with a given text. There are some pages in my working application that have hidden buttons with the same text as the target. I need there to be some manner of explicit wait, as some pages take a few seconds to load the elements in. The current implementation does not work because it is waiting for all elements to become visible, when some of them will never load a visible element.

I need a way to wait for some amount of time for the elements that will become visible, but not throw an exception when not all of them do.

```
public void clickButtonByText(String buttonText) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, PAGE_COMPONENT_LOADING_AVERAGE_TIME);
    String xpath = "//button[normalize-space(text())='" + buttonText + "']";
    WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);}
```

Comment: it's waiting for a specific button to become visible, but not the right one.  You just need to narrow your XPATH selector down to the one that you want to click.  Also change your expected condition to elementToBeClickable.  That will wait til it's visible and clickable.

Comment: elementToBeClickable might be what I need here, but I think that would still be waiting for the invisible elements. Like I said, I am trying to develop a generic method that I can use for all cases, if possible. If that is not doable then I will take anther approach, but that is what I am trying now.

Comment: OK, just be aware that visibilityOfElementLocated, returns 1 webelement reference... the first one it finds that matches the XPATH locator.  The XPATH is what you want to redefine in this code... if you are instead trying to get an array of webelements you want to use another expected condition.

Comment: I had worked with an array of elements before, but I was having a different issue while waiting for them to be visible. Perhaps what I need to try is to return all elements and iterate through to find the one that is clickable.

Comment: Seems like building xpath like: String xpath = "//button[text()='" + buttonText+ "']";  Would work.. then do  List<WebElement> elements =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpather))); Then check expected condition of clickable on each one... (first check that the List is not empty...)  You won't need to wait there...  expected condition returns a bool... if it's clickable, click it and end loop.

Comment: actually my bad, expected condition of elementToBeClickable returns a WebElement or null I think...

Comment: Have you tried implicit waits?
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help. This is what I've come up with, and it seems to be working.

```
public void clickButtonByText(String buttonText) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, PAGE_COMPONENT_LOADING_AVERAGE_TIME);
    String xpath = "//button[normalize-space(text())='" + buttonText + "']";
    List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpath)));
    for (WebElement button : elements)  {
        if (button.isDisplayed())   {
            button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
            clickWithJs(buttonText + " button clicked.", button, PAGE_COMPONENT_LOADING_MIN_TIME);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```